# How do I impress my ghost buddy?

Tags: caveblazers

Caveblazers has a blessing you can find called the Blessing of Generosity.

The description reads:

> Creates a ghostly wraith which follows you. Impress him and he may show his generosity.

What specific behaviour should I take to impress him?